# Constraints to be set for x position

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints

I've a scenario where in I've to display four circles. These should be in center of screen. I tried to place x and top constraint but this doesn't works fine for iPhone 4 device.

[image: Screenshot 1]

What constraints should I set so that all four circles should appear in center for all iPhone device?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Further, there is UICollectionView in bottom. I tried to set the top, left, w and height but this didn't worked.

Any solution?

[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Embed your 4 circle in UIView.

2) Set UIView constraint top, fixed width,fixed height and horizontal center

3) Now Select all 4 circle and set constraint like top, leading,trailing,bottom and equal width.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about the UICollectionView constraints?

Comment: top,leading,trailing,bottom

Comment: Yes..missing height constraint

Comment: You want fixed width?

Comment: See there is dynamic content in collectionview. Width shall remain same but height may increase based on content.

Comment: Then divide your screen in two UIView. First View contains above data and below contains collectionview.

Comment: For First view set fixed height and for Second view set all 4 constraint which I have said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117047/discussion-between-jayprakash-dubey-and-bhadresh-mulsaniya).