# How to add constraint to right align an image inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

**Problem :** 
I am trying to set constraints in storyboard for an image so that it is always aligned to the right inside UITableViewCell

I am setting the trailing space, top and bottom space, height and width of the image.

The image then goes outside the tableview. (Screenshot-1)

The applied constraints from attribute inspector view is shown in screenshot-2

I am using Xcode Version 11.0

[image]

[image]

**What i tried:**

1) Tried suggestions from this stack overflow thread 
[Constraints to be set for x position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321280/constraints-to-be-set-for-x-position)
This is close to what i am looking for but doesn’t seem to work in my case.

2) Set up trailing space, top and bottom space, height and width of the image.

3) Enclosed the image in a UI View and tried step 2

4) Set up only top or bottom space to the container, add width, height constraints

5) Tried applying space constraints to the table cell rather than the container.

In all the cases, the image goes outside the tableview.

**Question￼**

How can satisfy the constraint in such a way the image is aligned to the right inside UITableViewCell.

Please let me know if i am missing something or if you need any other information to provide your inputs.

Screenshot on clicking the constraint

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the trailing constraint and change it's firstItem attribute to leading instead as currently you do

> trailingOfImage + 7 = leadingOfCell

Which make it outside the cell

Comment: Thanks. This brought the image inside the cell. I dragged the image to the right and updated constraint constants.Now I get a warning expected x=-62, actual x=288. Not sure i am doing this correctly. can you please let me know how to set the constraint so the warning would go away.

Comment: make sure constant value is 20

Comment: I updated the constant to 20 but the warning doesn't go away.

Comment: from the screenshot you shared untick `Relatibe to margin` and select `Leading`

Comment: Thanks. This solved the problem. One other issue i had was that i did not add constraint to the tableview. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is dont enclose image in uiview 
Step1 give it a left constraint Example 0 or 1
Step 2 give it top and bottom constraint 
Step 3 give it a fixed width 
Step 4 ctl drag label and drop on image view
Step 5 center vertical 
Step 6 give lable left constraint 
Step 7 give label fixed height
Step 8 give label right constraint

Hope that helps

Comment: can you please clarify why the label should be linked here. Assuming that the label is not there, how do i add constraint to just align the image